# Create a column with dollar sign in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, create-table, dollar-sign

I am wondering whether I can create a column with dollar sign? The output should look like the area marked by red line. But the column can still be calculated like number.

I am not sure whether it is capable.
[image]

Comment: Huh?  I do not understand.  Your image answers your own question.  Store numbers as numbers, and you can format them however you wish in the select statement, or by whatever software is rendering the presentation.

Comment: @OldProgrammer thank you for your reply. I was wondering whether I can create a column from beginning that contains $. Not use CONCAT in the select statement to add $ in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
select to_char(500, '$999') from dual
```

**Column-Name with Dollar:**

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (ID int, "$Sal" int);
INSERT INTO t1 values(1,100);
SELECT id, "$Sal" * 10 FROM t1;
```

Comment: Please consider accepting if it solved the problem !

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But is it means with dollar sign, the column cant be calculated. I see you are using varchar2, so it is a string? there is no a specific data type for currency that has dollar sign and can be calculated at the same time?

Comment: Added an example with INT datatype

Comment: You want the column itself - the stored data - to be of data type NUMBER.  That way you can always do whatever math operations you require.  TO_CHAR is strictly for _presenting_ that number as a character string for human consumption.  Even if you simply 'SELECT NUM_COL FROM MYTABLE', if the output is not being used internally, oracle will implicitly use TO_CHAR to convert the stored binary value into numeric characters for human consumption.